# Define cross directory dependencies in Jam

Tags: build, build-tools, jam

After many years of using make, I've just started using jam (actually ftjam) for my projects.

In my project workspaces, I have two directories:

- `src` where I build executables and libraries
- `test` where my test programs are

I'm trying to set up a dependency on test programs so that each time I compile them, the libraries will be recompiled as well (if they need to).

Any suggestion on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok this seems to be not an as easy question as I thought so I worked out a solution on my own. It uses a script to achieve the end result so I still hope that a Jam guru will have a jam-only solution.

- Create a Jamrules in the root directory of the project with the common definitions.
- Create a Jamfile in the root directory of the project with the following content:

```
    SubDir . ;
    SubInclude . src ;
    SubInclude . test ;
```

- Create a Jamfile in the src directory

```
    SubDir .. src ;
    Library mylib : mylib.c ;
```

- Create a Jamfile in the test directory

```
    SubDir .. test ;
    Main mytest : mytest.c ; 
    Depends mytest :  mylib$(SUFLIB) ;
```

With this setting, as long as I am in the root directory, whenever I try to build mytest the library will also be recompiled (if needed). I found an old message on the jammer mailing list describing it.

Alas this doesn't work if I'm in the test subdirectory since jam can only look *down* into subdirectories.

So, I created a simple script called `jmk` and put it together with the `jam` executable (so that both are in the path):

```
if [ "$JMKROOT" = "" ] ; then
   JMKROOT=`pwd`
   export JMKROOT
fi
cd $JMKROOT
jam $*
```

and I set the JMKROOT environment variable to the root of my project.

For when I compile in a Windows shell (that's why I want to use Jam) I simply use this small `jmk.bat` batch file:

```
@echo off
if "%JMKROOT%" EQU "" set JMKROOT=%CD%

set OLDCD=%CD%
cd %JMKROOT%
jam %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

cd %OLDCD%
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jam in [one of my projects](http://github.com/Andromeda-OS/LLVM), and I am encountering your very situation. I have my executable programs in the `bin` subdirectory, and my static libraries are kept in the `lib` subdirectory.

In my top-level Jamfile, I type in `SubDir TOP ;`. This initializes the `$(TOP)` variable to point to the directory containing this Jamfile. I then add lines such as `SubInclude TOP bin llvm-tblgen` and `SubInclude TOP lib Support`, which adds the contents of the Jamfiles in `bin/llvm-tblgen` and `lib/Support` to the build.

In the Jamfile in `bin/llvm-tblgen`, I type in `SubDir TOP bin llvm-tblgen ;`. I do the same in the Jamfile in `lib/Support`, but I use `SubDir TOP lib Support ;` instead. The key when entering `SubDir` rules is to type in the names of each subdirectory from the `TOP` to the directory containing this Jamfile.

Then, when it is time to set the linkline of my executable target, I reference the support library like this: `$(TOP)/lib/Support/libLLVMSupport.a`. Jam expands this path into the location of `libLLVMSupport.a`, relative to where I run Jam, even if I cd into the `bin/llvm-tblgen` directory and run Jam manually from there.

This makes it very easy to manage large projects that contain cross-directory dependencies. This solution, unlike your earlier one, lets you run Jam directly. Hope it helps you!